# Bilinear form representation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

It is known, that the following result holds: let $X,Y$ be compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mathbb{R}^M$ respectively and let $B:C(X)\times C(Y)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bilinear form ($C(X)$ is the space of continuous functions on $X$), such that 
$$B(u,v)\geq 0 \quad \text{if} \quad u,v\geq 0.$$ 
Then, there exists a finite positive Radon measure $m\in M^+(X\times Y)$ such that
$$B(u,v)=\langle m, u\otimes v\rangle=\int_{X\times Y}u(x)v(y)d m(x,y).$$

The proof of this result, based on the theory of Hilbert-Schmidt operators, can be found in Tartar L. *$H$-measures, a new approach for studying homogenisation, oscillations and concentration effects in partial differential equations.*

Naturally, one may expect that dropping positivity assumption on $B$ would result in a signed measure $m$ instead of a positive one, however this is not the case - the positivity is essential (at least in that proof), to obtain $m$.

That said, I'm curious if there is a similar result, where positivity of $B$ is not assumed, but still yields a Radon measure representation.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't $X$ be a compact set, or $C(X)$ consist of almost compactly supported functions or something like that?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker We can assume $X$ and $Y$ to be compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mathbb{R}^M$ respectively (I updated the post)

Comment: @PietroMajer Indeed, I forgot to update that part as well.

Comment: If you drop the positivity requirement then the result no longer holds (so it is not merely the case that the previous proof now fails, the desired conclusion is not true in general). Continuous bilinear forms on $C(X)\times C(Y)$ are sometimes known as _bimeasures_ and this is all related to various things concerning Grothendieck's inequality/theorem

Comment: In other words, the linear  continuous map $C(X)\otimes C(Y)\to C(X\times Y)$ induced by the point-wise product $(f,g)\mapsto f(x)g(y)$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: The point of Yemon's comment is that $C(X\times Y)\cong C(X)\tilde{\otimes}_\varepsilon C(Y)$, the *injective* tensor product, but $B$ induces only a continuous linear functional on the much smaller *projective* tensor product $C(X)\tilde{\otimes}_\pi C(Y)$. This is a beast, even for $X=Y=[0,1]$ no satisfactory representation is known.